# How to Disable NSLog inside Library or Framework? e.g. Admob Library

Tags: objective-c, ios, admob, nslog

Admob and iAd are alway print log when the banner are not available. 
is it possible to disable it?

Answer (score 3):

You should file a bug with the vendor and hope they agree with your position.